# Why is $i^2$ not equal to $1$?

Tags: proof-verification

I've only recently started learning about imaginary numbers, and there is one thing I cannot really wrap my head around:

$i^2 = i*i = {\sqrt{-1}} * {\sqrt{-1}} = {\sqrt{(-1) * (-1)}} = {\sqrt{1}} = 1$

I'm aware that by definition $i^2 = -1$, but as far as I know, even definitions have to obey mathematical rules.

So where is the mistake? :)

---

EDIT:

Thank you all, seems like the wrong bit is ${\sqrt{-1}}*{\sqrt{-1}}$

Cheers :)

Comment: Because $\sqrt a \cdot \sqrt b = \sqrt{ab}$ may not hold for negative $a$ or negative $b$.

Comment: @fygesser Are you sure that $\sqrt{1} = 1$? Why not $\sqrt{1} = -1$ (because $(-1)^2 = 1$)? Do you see the flaw? As always, $\sqrt{-1}$ is very dangerous, especially when dealing with complex numbers.

Comment: @flawr But $\sqrt x$ for non-negative $x$ is the principal square root of $x$, and $\sqrt 1 = 1$.

Comment: Certain mathematical rules do not apply to imaginary numbers. You can actually prove contradictions if you naively apply all normal mathematical rules to imaginary numbers- which is one of the reasons they were abandoned for a good few decades after they were first used, because mathematicians saw them as useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a confusion about how to treat $\sqrt{x}$, here.

If we want a *function* called "square root," then this function will not be very well-behaved - in general, we will not have $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ for $a, b$ not both positive. This will break the third equality in your argument.

If we want to talk about "square root" as a *relation*, then we will always have "$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$," in the sense that, if $x$ and $y$ are square roots of $a$ and $b$, respectively, then $xy$ is a square root of $ab$. But we won't have statements like "$\sqrt{1}=1$" - the last equality in your argument will break.

Generally, when we speak of square roots, we are talking about the function version, so "$\sqrt{1}=1$" is correct, but $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ need not be.

---

EDIT: Note that what your argument has done is show - perfectly rigorously! - that there is no function $f(x)$ defined on all of $\mathbb{C}$, satisfying

- $f(x)^2=x$,
- $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, and
- $f(1)=1$.

Comment: You can see this issue in the comments - peterwhy is speaking of $\sqrt{x}$ as a function, and flawr is speaking of $\sqrt{x}$ as a relation.

Comment: oh ok. I would blame people who call $\sqrt\cdot$ function for non-negative real input as "square root" instead of principal square root, hiding the fact that there are up to two square roots of a number, and at the same time leading some other people to think that $\sqrt 4 = \pm 2$ is true.

Comment: @peterwhy I see no reason to blame people who call the $\sqrt{\ }$ function defined on the non-negative real halfline, the square root function, and no reason either to think that $\sqrt{4}=\pm2$ since $\sqrt{\ }$ is real valued and $\pm2$ is not a real number.